# Как правильно перенести строку на 2 строки в списке по правилам PEP8?

Tags: python

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = [float(i)for i in a.replace(',', '.').split(';')] + [float(i)for i in b.replace(',', '.').split(';')]
```

как правильно перенести, чтобы записано было в 2 строки? просто тут список, нет никаких запятых после которых можно было бы ставить знак переноса `/`

Comment: После `+` можно поставить перенос. И знак переноса - \, а не /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

а так не устраивает?

```
x1, y1 = [float(i) for i in a.replace(',', '.').split(';')]
x2, y2 = [float(i) for i in b.replace(',', '.').split(';')]
```

можно сделать код покороче:

```
x1, y1 = map(float, a.replace(',', '.').split(';'))
x2, y2 = map(float, b.replace(',', '.').split(';'))
```

можно сделать код короткий и в 1 строчку:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(float, (a + ";" + b).replace(',', '.').split(';'))
```